# How to add a specific application in gnome-pie?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, shortcuts

All I want to do for now is just adding the terminal in gnome-pie applications. The thing is, I don't even know what should I type in "command to execute" path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `gnome-terminal`

One remark: It is much easier to configure Gnome-Pie by **drag and drop**: Simply search for the Terminal in your main menu and drag it to the Pie's preview!

Second remark: Nearly all of your application links (desktop files) are stored in `/usr/share/applications`! You can navigate with your file browser to this directory (**File System -> usr -> share -> applications**) and drag your desired applications to the configuration menu!

Comment: wow, I didn't know about the drag and drop feature in gnome pie. That was so much easier then I expected! Thanks Simon